# Sort collection while iterating through it

Tags: java

I want to loop through an ArrayList of Objects, which is sorted by one of the Object's attributes, which is an Integer (with Collections.sort() ). If a certain condition is met, i want to modify that attribute by adding +60. Now, I want to resort my collection, hoping that I will get to the same object again at a bigger index.

Does that make sense, considering that I'm iterating through the ArrayList while sorting it new?

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
Collection.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(Order::getInt);

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
   Object dummy = list.get(i);

   if (dummy < 8) {
      dummy.setInt(8+60);
      Collection.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(Order::getInt);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dreamcrash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66815731/3788176) is sufficient for this case, because your criterion will only be true until the element is updated: `8 + 60 >= 8`, so you don't need to update it again.

But if there was a chance the elements could need updating again, you can proceed like this:

Because the list is already sorted, there is no need to re-sort it: just find the new insertion location, add the item there and remove it from the old location.

How you find the new location is up to you: you could search linearly, binary search etc.

You then just have to make sure that you process the same `i` again, because you need to process the element which follows the one you moved.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
   Dummy dummy = list.get(i);

   if (condition(dummy)) {
      int newIndex = /* however you like */
      update(dummy);
      list.add(newIndex, dummy);
      list.remove(i);
      --i;
   }
}
```

A more efficient way to move the element would be to rotate the sublist between `i` and `newIndex` by 1 position:

```
Dummy old = list.get(i);
for (int j = i + 1; j < newIndex; ++j) {
  list.set(j - 1, list.get(j));
}
list.set(newIndex, old);
```

Or you could probably just use:

```
Collections.rotate(list.subList(i, newIndex), 1);
```

The reason this could be more efficient is that it avoids shifting unaffected elements twice: adding something at `newIndex` means you have to shift all the subsequent elements along by one; removing something at `i` means you have to shift all subsequent elements along by one.

Answer (score 2):

More performant and easier would be to apply the operation first and then sort in the end:

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

for (Object dummy : list) {
   if (dummy < 8) {
      dummy.setInt(8+60);
   }
}
Collection.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(Order::getInt);
```

Furthermore, in your original approach, you are iteration through the list and then changing it by sorting, which is almost always not a good idea. Consequently, it can lead to a situation that you will be skipping objects, because after the sorting phase those objects may end up in an index below the one that you are currently working with.